# Android Navigation Drawer without Listview

Tags: android

i want to create a swipe menu like navigation drawer. But there is going to be textviews and imageviews, like a half activity. Is it possible to make this?

Comment: Do you know a tutorial about it? Because all i can found was on Android Developer page and Androidhive, witch was using adapters and listviews.

Comment: You have to use a ListView for that. There is no better alternative.

Comment: Then how can i add my TextView's and ImageView's on ListView, i mean how can i make it doesn't look like ListView?

Comment: Use a custom adapter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `NavigationDrawer` from support library.

Include a `FrameLayout` as a child of the `DrawerLayout` and make the `android:layout_gravity="left"`. Then put anything you want in it. You do not have to use only `ListView`. What you put in a view that has left gravity will be the left menu

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. This is tutorial for [navigation drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

and you can create custom fragment instead of listview. use fragment to display slider menu

Answer (score 1):

I did it in this way:
Created a ListView with only one child (row) with a Layout of what I want inside it.

Here the code:

```
        // Add Header
    ListAdapter adapter = new BaseAdapter() {

        Object mObj = new Object(); // Unusefull

        @Override
        public int getCount() { return 1; }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) { return mObj; }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if( convertView == null )
            {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.drawer_layout, null );
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    };

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    if (mDrawerList != null)
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```